# Converting a text string value from a spinner into a number for future calculation

Tags: android

I'm hoping to get some ideas on a solution to a problem I couldn't find elsewhere. I would like to use a numerical value assigned to a text spinner selection in a calculation while keeping the spinner display as the text value the user selected.  For example, if the user chooses "pizza", I'd like the pizza be displayed but the numerical value assigned to pizza to be saved and used in a future calculation.

Is this something that could be done in app builder, or something I'd need to do from scratch?

Here's my diagram:

1. Spinner A (text)---->numerical value is listed in list
2. Spinner B(number)
3. User Input A (number)
4. User Input B (number)
5. Calculate----> Numerical value of spinner A + Spinner B + User Input A + User Input
   B
6. Display Result

Comment: Why is this tagged javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use an array

```
var spinnerVals = [];

spinnerVals.push[ spinnerVals.length ] = [ snipperValue, number ];
spinnerVals[ spinnerVals.length ] = [ "userInput", number ];

for( var i = 0, result = 0; i < spinnerVals.length; i++ ) {
    result += spinnerVals[i][1];
}
```